# Return html from a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a decorator, but it would be the same problem if I were using a helper.

All I am attempting to do is display a user_ma,e/

I have this embedded ruby tag:

```
<%= decorate_user_name %>
```

And here is the helper / decorator method:

```
def decorate_user_name
    "prepended string #{h.link_to('my_link', h.my_link_path )}"
end
```

However, this returns this html:

```
"prepended string  <a href="/forums">my_link</a>"
```

Why are there quotation marks around the html, and why is the link not shown? (The above a tag is **literally** shown on the page)

I could use html safe, but couldn't this open up some danger? What if I wanted to do this:

```
def decorate_user_name
    "#{model.username}!".html_safe
end
```

and someone set their username to

`<script> $(document).ready( function(){  alert("hello, just mentioning that I'm mucking about with this website!") } </script>`

See the problem?

I'd have a validation to stop a username with those characters being created in the first place, but I don't want to have to rely on a validation. The method should display safe html regardless.

Is one option to create a partial and render the partial from the decorator / helper method? Would you want to do this if you had more complex html? Or would you use a `content_tag`?

Answer (score 0):

When you interpolate the link it gets "converted" to a String. In your example is not clear how you are planning to use `decorate_example`, but based on your concern I'm assuming that it receives user input data.

My suggestion is to put the string outside the decorator and return only the link:

```
prepended string
<%= decorate_example %>

def decorate_example
  link_to 'my_link', my_link_path
end
```